# Loading dynamic external form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hope someone could help me.

When i load an external php that generates a set of fields, i have no problems, but then i send the generated form, i can not access the vars.

There is the code i user:

For load the external file:

```
      $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "product-insert.php",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    global: true,
    processData:true,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {num_filas: $("#num_filas").val()},

    success: function(html){
             $("#destino").html(html);
             alert(html);
             str = $("ofertas").serialize();
    },

    error: function(){
    },

    complete: function(){
    }
});


  <form action="ofertas.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form-ofertas" id="ofertas" >

  <div id="destino"></div>
```

The file loaded have this code:

```
echo '<input name="campo" type="hidden" value="valor" />';
```

and the php file that receive the form have this code:

```
die("campo: ".$_REQUEST['campo']);
```

I really will appreciate a lot the help.

Thnx in advance.

Yannick

Comment: Need more complete data. Where are you loading it? Where are you posting it to? If done correctly, it should work.

Comment: Is `#destino` within the `<form>` you're submitting?

Comment: @Kerry "if done correctly, it should work" is my quote of the day ;) @Sauron what do you mean by "cannot access the vars"? When?

Comment: Hi 

Yes, the Div destino is within the :


  <form action="ofertas.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form-ofertas" id="ofertas" >

<div id="destino"></div>
</form>

Comment: @Pekka i mean that i can not receive the vars  of the dynamic loaded form, when i click submit the form.

Thnx to all for your help :)

Comment: @SauronZ - Are you sure they're getting loaded?  if you alert the html in the `sucess`, what are you seeing?

Comment: @Nick Craver.

Here is the result code, so is getting loaded fine.
<code>
<input name="campo" type="hidden" value="valor" />
</code>

Comment: @SauronZ - Did you add those code tags or is that in the response?

Comment: @Nick Craver - Sorry, i put them to try formatting the code.

Comment: @SauronZ - I added an answer below for what seems to be your issue, and for future reference: [How to format code in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments) :)

Comment: @SauronZ - Your comment says `get` your question says `post`....which method are you actually using?

Comment: @Nick Craver  - Sorry for the confusion. Im using post., but i have tried with get and nothing.

Comment: Can you confirm using firebug that the form elements are actually being included in the form?

Comment: Yes, elements are inluded, but i see in firebug that when sending the form, none of the loaded html content is sent with the subit.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment, you're checking for `$_POST['campo']` despite the fact that your `<form>` tag's method is a GET request.  You should instead check the value of `$_GET['campo']` (or `$_REQUEST['campo']`).

Comment: i've tried, but still not working 

:(

I think problem is that the values of the form dinamically loaded are not sent when click the submit button.

Maybe if i send the form using jquery will work?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `</form>` tag? You didn't include it in your question if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing partially off comments here, your form looks like this:

```
<form action="ofertas.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
 name="form-ofertas" id="ofertas"> 
  <div id="destino"></div> 
</form>
```

Your [method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) is `GET`, which won't give you what you're after if you're looking for the values in the `POST` collection, which [`$_POST`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) does.  Just change the method on your form to `method="post"` to get this working correctly, otherwise use [`$_GET`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) on the PHP side, if a GET is what you're actually after.

For a good discussion of GET vs POST, take a look here:
[When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Comment: @Nick Craver

I have updated the code, but still not working.

The mistake of POST and GET was due to so many changes :)

Comment: @SauronZ - now you have 2 `success` functions defined...need that not to be the case, remove the first and put the `alert()` in the second, what's the result then?

Comment: @Nick Craver - Removed in code and in example, but still the same.I really don't know what can be happening :(

Comment: @SauronZ - I don't know what's run from the info provided...any chance there's a page I can hit?

Comment: @Nick Craver- http://ulzama.es/admin/ofertas.phpn=1   - User/pass: Nick
  - Press the second Radio button and continue. Then you have the form. Simply enter 2 in the last field and click Añadir productos, it will load the external field.  Really thnx for your patience

Comment: @SauronZ - I had to run for dinner, can't login now though, let me know if you can re-enable it.